# How to send array byte of a pdf file via soapUI

Tags: java, pdf, arrays, soapui

I'm testing a `wsdl` file via `SoapUI` and want to send `byte[]` of a pdf file to client. `byte[]` are received at client side, but the created pdf file is blank. Below is what I have done :

SoapUI response script :

```
 def groovyUtils = new com.eviware.soapui.support.GroovyUtils( context )
 byte[] pdfBytes = new File(groovyUtils.projectPath + "//file1.pdf").text.getBytes( 'UTF-8' )
 requestContext.pdfBytes = pdfBytes.encodeBase64()
```

Java code :

```
 byte[] bytes = getFileFromServer();
 File f = new File(filePath);

 try {
FileOutputStream fileOuputStream = new FileOutputStream(f); 
    fileOuputStream.write(bytes);
    fileOuputStream.close();                            
 } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
    LOG.error("FileNotFoundException", e);
 } catch (IOException e) {
LOG.error("IOException", e);
 }
```

By using decode, the created file is damamged :

```
 bytes = Base64.decodeBase64(bytes);
```

Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the problem - or at least *a* problem:

```
new File(groovyUtils.projectPath + "//file1.pdf").text
```

You're loading a *binary* file as if it's *text*. It's not. Don't read it as text and then convert it to byte - use

```
byte[] pdfBytes = new File(groovyUtils.projectPath + "//file1.pdf").bytes
```

Comment: Oh! Thanks a lot. but is it ok that I don´t specify charset?